# by using sql i need to get below mentioned result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables with below kind of data.

`Shift` (`shiftcode varchar2(10)`)

```
shiftcode
A
B
C
```

`emp_dt` (`sn number(10), empno number(10), dt date`)

```
SN  Empno   Date
1   157 01/01/2016
2   157 02/01/2016
3   157 03/01/2016
4   157 04/01/2016
5   157 05/01/2016
6   157 06/01/2016
7   157 07/01/2016
8   157 08/01/2016
9   157 09/01/2016
10  157 10/01/2016
11  157 11/01/2016
12  157 12/01/2016
```

Here I need to map each employee with rotation of shiftcode.

If employee shift starts with B then it has to rotate like B,A,C,A,B,C,...

We are using toad for our development. by using sql or pl/sql i need to get my result.

My result should be

```
SN  Emp No  Date    Shift Code
1   157 01/01/2016  B
2   157 02/01/2016  C
3   157 03/01/2016  A
4   157 04/01/2016  B
5   157 05/01/2016  C
6   157 06/01/2016  A
7   157 07/01/2016  B
8   157 08/01/2016  C
9   157 09/01/2016  A
10  157 10/01/2016  B
11  157 11/01/2016  C
12  157 12/01/2016  A
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, show us what you got, and where you run into problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the modulus of the SN-column to assign the shift codes.

(working with numbers is easier in this case,so consider shift code A=0,B=1,C=2)

```
select SN,empno,dt, mod((SN-1),3) shift_no
from emp_dt
```

For the modulus I used SN-1 so that the result for first record (with SN=1)  corresponds with shift code A.

the result should be something like this:

```
SN  Emp No  Date    shift_no
1   157 01/01/2016  0 // A
2   157 02/01/2016  1 // B
3   157 03/01/2016  2 // C
```

if you add a column to the emp_dt table for the initial shiftcode you can simply add this to the modulus

```
select SN,empno,dt, mod((SN-1)+init_shiftcode,3) shift_no
from emp_dt
```

for an employee with init_shiftcode 1 (= shift code B) the result would be:

```
SN  Emp No  Date    shift_no
1   157 01/01/2016  1 // B
2   157 02/01/2016  2 // C
3   157 03/01/2016  0 // A
...
```

Comment: This logic perfectly worked for me.Thanks neb for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try below. You will still need to join shift code table.

```SQL
SELECT DISTINCT SN
    ,EmpNO
    ,convert(DATE, DATE) dt
    ,CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATE) = 'Monday'
            THEN 'B'
        WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATE) = 'Tuesday'
            THEN 'C'
        WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATE) = 'Wednesday'
            THEN 'A'
        WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATE) = 'Thursday'
            THEN 'B'
        WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATE) = 'Friday'
            THEN 'C'
        WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATE) = 'Saturday'
            THEN 'A'
        WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATE) = 'Sunday'
            THEN 'B'
        END
FROM emp_dt
```